# How to implement efficient heterogeneous microservice data queries?

Tags: graph, distributed-computing, dsl, query, microservices

Our team has an idea of implementing a simple declarative DSL that would let users query the enterprise's domain model via a single interface without caring which specific microservices to call to get specific portions of data and how to then relate and combine them.

Suggested syntax is based on SQL, but:

- Is much more limited: no grouping or aggregation, no explicit subqueries, no functions etc.
- Joins cannot be specified and are only implicit based on the predefined schema (entities and relations).

Example:

```sql
SELECT entityTypeOne.name, entityTypeTwo.value, entityTypeTwo.date
 WHERE entityTypeOne.name LIKE 'Sample%'
   AND entityTypeTwo.date BETWEEN (2015-05-01, 2015-05-31)
```

Expected result:

```
╔════════╦═══════╦════════════╗
║  name  ║ value ║    date    ║
╠════════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ London ║  1000 ║ 01/05/2015 ║
║ London ║  2000 ║ 02/05/2015 ║
║ London ║  3000 ║ 03/05/2015 ║
║ Moscow ║  2000 ║ 02/05/2015 ║
║ Moscow ║  9000 ║ 05/05/2015 ║
║ Tokyo  ║  1000 ║ 30/05/2015 ║
╚════════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

The underlying entity-relation schema knows that entities are related like this: `entityTypeOne.id = entityTypeTwo.parentId` which creates an implicit join.

The "query engine" should know that it will first query the *entityTypeTwo* microservice applying the date range filtering on server, then *entityTypeOne* microservice applying the *id* filtering based on previous query's result.

The problems we currently see:

1. Representing the object-relation schema.
2. Figuring out the optimal order of querying.
3. Denormalizing resulting data.

I was wondering if this is a known problem and if there are any algorithms to check (maybe something from graph theory)?

This is the closest thing I could find so far:

[What is a heterogeneous query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6387/48112)

If it makes things simpler we can assume that microservices are exposing data via OData.

Comment: I *believe* this is similar to what GraphQL was designed for. I don't have a lot of experience with it, but it might give you a starting point. https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/05/01/graphql-introduction.html
https://learngraphql.com/basics/introduction

Answer (score 2):

If what you are trying to do is present a single endpoint to many APIs, you might find some value in Netflix' [Falcor](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/) project.

Falcor is not a query engine. It is a library for "efficient data fetching." It is one example of a growing set of tools delivering "[Demand Driven Architectures](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/domain-driven-architecture)" -- alternatives to traditional rest services that allow the author of a client tool to specify what they want in terms related to a canonical data model, thus obviating the need to develop UIs (the demand) in tandem with a backend. The "fetch" tools translate the canonical model into calls to individual rest services, and a combination of in-browser and reverse proxy caches make things efficient by avoiding subsequent calls to the data services for the same data.

To paraphrase Falcor lead author Jafar Husein: picture your service graph not as a bunch of discrete services, but as a single massive JSON Graph document. That is what users feel they are making requests of -- and Falcor handles the necessary caching, batching and routing that make it efficient.

It's almost as if these tools bring SELECT and WHERE clause behavior to a collection of REST APIs. And while that's not quite the same as building an efficient query API on top of REST, it may offer you the same benefits -- without your having to invent an efficient query processor, which frankly could take years.